# Need some help using timer interrupt for a clock in c

Tags: c, timer, interrupt, microcontroller, clock

I have my circuit made and have it displaying 4 different digits on the 7 segment display with Hours:Minutes format. I now want it to use timer interrupts and for it to continuously run through the time using something small like a second for the hours so even smaller for minutes, just to see if it works ok. This is all i need help with im not sure what how to use timer interrupts, just need this as the next step. Thank you

here is the circuit so far using P89c668 microcontroller - http://imgur.com/YJKQ206[1] only difference is i'm using buffers not transistors

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with your microcontroler but the principal is the same.

`1.Use an 8 or 16 bit timer.`
`2.Set specific bits in registers to accuratelly set the interrupt interval`
`3.When the timer overflows an interrupt happens(a function is called automatically)`
`4.In this function you increase a variable.`
`5.Translate the (variable * interrupt interval) to hours and minutes.`

valter